# useing $page_title within a echo

Tags: php

I want this to work, it doesn't currently, so, if its possible, what do I need to change:

```
<?php echo $page_title_LEADER; ?>
```

In the config file I have

```
define('ENGLAND_LEADER', 'Bob Smith:');
define('SPAIN_LEADER', 'Stan Smith:');
```

which when I use:

```
<?php echo ENGLAND_LEADER; ?>
```

works fine as you would expect, what I'm trying to do is use the page title to auto fill the `COUNTRY` name part of `COUNTRY_LEADER`, so I don't have to manually change the name of the country each time.

NB I do have the `$page_title` set in the page

Comment: plz show us some codes, we cant imagine your codes

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. We need some more information - can you please supply the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: Thanks guys but the chap below fixed it instantly.

Comment: Someone suggested an edit to the question title, but as its been answered i rejected the edits, also the edit used words i don't understand, so hardly a useful tool for others asking the same question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [constant](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function for this

```
<?php echo constant($page_title . '_LEADER') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked instantly (with ?> at the end, i almsot missed that lol) thanks very much for your quick comment